# How do I import/use a generic overloaded operator function?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

I have a Kotlin class which is the base for other classes, and want to define an operator `times` to be used with its derived classes.

In Base.kt

```
abstract class Base<Q : Base<Q>> internal constructor(open protected val rawValue: Long)
   : Comparable<Q> {

    // allows Q * Double
    operator fun times(factor: Double) = selfFactory(rawValue * factor) 
    // selfFactory instantiates an object of derived type Q
}

// Supposed to allow Double * Q
internal operator fun <Q : Base<Q>> Double.times(factor: Q) = factor * this
```

In Derived.kt

```
data class Derived internal constructor(override val rawValue: Long) 
   : Base<Derived>(rawValue) {
     
}
```

In some other file

```
import com.mycompany.Derived

fun foo(d: Derived): Derived = 5.0 * d;  // doesn't find the operator
```

How can I import this generic operator to allow `Double * Q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator is defined in Base.kt file.

So, assuming the base.kt file in located in the package `com.mycompany` you just need to import the operator times : `com.mycompany.times`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the operator function returns `Q`, not `Base<Q>`. Otherwise, at your use site in `foo()`, it will be trying to return `Base<Derived>` instead of `Derived`, which is not necessarily the same thing.

Maybe it already does, but I don't know what `selfFactory()` looks like.

It's good practice to be explicit about declaring return types of public functions, even if you're using the `=` notation.

If your use site is not in the same package you defined the extension function in, you need to import it. You can hover the cursor over the `*` inside `foo()` if you want the IDE to offer to add the import for you.

You marked it `internal` so it will not be visible in other modules.